# How to draw JMS queue?

Tags: java, jms, diagram

Is there any symbol for JMS queue? I know e.g. databases, files, classes should be drawn in the same way, but what about JMS elements?

Comment: Are you considering some specific graphic modeling language like UML, or you are looking for some general-use symbol for custom architecture diagrams?

Comment: @ArtursLicis I needed it to prepare one simple drawing. Just didn't want faux pas :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are considering custom (high level) architecture diagrams, you could use cloud symbol (however, in my personal opinion it's more for topics), or those found in this tutorial: [Basic JMS Concepts](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bncdx.html)

Answer (score 9):

There is a great book called "Enterprise Integration Patterns" which has a nice visual language and symbol for messaging systems, here is a link to the diagram they use for a queue http://www.eaipatterns.com/MessageChannel.html

http://www.eaipatterns.com/downloads.html has a stencils for Visio with all the shapes from the book.

Comment: to complete your answer: the icon is a horizontal cylinder.